# Testing angular form submitting

Tags: javascript, html, angular, forms, properties

I am testing an angular app and especially this HTML input:

```html
<form  name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">
     <input type="text" name="nombre" id="field_nombre"
                     [(ngModel)]="paciente.nombre" required/>
(etc. f.e. button on submit...)
```

Here is my component:

```html
imports....


export class PacienteDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    
    paciente: Paciente;
    
    ....
    
       save() {
        this.isSaving = true;
        if (this.paciente.id !== undefined) {
            this.subscribeToSaveResponse(
                this.pacienteService.update(this.paciente));
        } else {
            this.subscribeToSaveResponse(
                this.pacienteService.create(this.paciente));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my patient.model.ts

```html
export class Paciente implements BaseEntity {
    constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public nombre?: string,
        public sexo?: Sexo,
        
        .....
```

I want to test the form which means that on submit it is really calling teh save() function.
I have this in my test:

```html
describe('Paciente Management Dialog Component', () => {
        let comp: PacienteDialogComponent;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<PacienteDialogComponent>;
        let debugElement: DebugElement; //create a debgElement for testing

        beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [OncosupTestModule,
                    OncosupSharedModule,
                    BrowserModule,
                    FormsModule,
                  
                ],
                declarations:...
                ],
                providers: [
                    ...
            })
            .compileComponents();
        }));

  beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(PacienteDialogComponent);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
        });
                //a default generated test which controls if the save method really saves a new patient with its name, id, sex, etc.
        it('Should call create service on save for new entity',
           inject([],
               fakeAsync(() => {
                   // GIVEN
                   const entity = new Paciente();
                   spyOn(service, 'create').and.returnValue(Observable.of(new HttpResponse({body: entity})));
                   comp.paciente = entity;
                   // WHEN
                   comp.save();
                   tick(); // simulate async

                   // THEN
                   expect(service.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(entity);
                   expect(comp.isSaving).toEqual(false);
                   expect(mockEventManager.broadcastSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'pacienteListModification', content: 'OK'});
                   expect(mockActiveModal.dismissSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
               })
           )
       );
// And teh second thing I want to test is if ngSubmit is really calling the save() function


           it ('should call the onSubmit method', async(() => {
            //fixture.detectChanges();
            spyOn(comp,'save');
            var1 = debugElement.query(By.css('button')).nativeElement;
            console.log('print button ' + var1);
            var1.click();
            expect(comp.save).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);//verify...
            }));

//And also if isSaving is set to true


 it ('should set isSaving to true', async(() => {
           comp.save();
            expect(comp.isSaving).toBeTruthy();
         
           }));
```

1.Now I have these questions:  The first test is generated by default and not written by me. In this line `const entity = new Paciente();` should I call parameters of Paciente? Like id, sex, name or leave it like this by default without parameters. Th epurpose of this first test if to check if really the save() function saves a patient and his data like id, sex, etc.

2.For the second test I read it in a tutorial of angular that: **HaveBennCalled(0)** is the right thing to test if this spy is called and how many times. But anyway does it really tests if the button calls the function save(). I think it only checks if thebutton haven´t been called before, but not if it is callled right now in save function.

3.**And are these 3 tests enough and complete for a form submitting?**

Comment: @trichetriche  this is a tricky one

Comment: It's not tricky at all : your test is useless. You create a value, set this value to your input, and expect the binding of that input to have the said value. This isn't a test you should do, you're just testing if Angular works here. You're supposed to test if your code works, not if a library works.

Comment: Think about your tests as this : **What would happen if the user ... ?**. For instance, *what would happen if the user doesn't input any value in this input ?* That's what you should test : that when you submit the form, this value is not empty.

Comment: This is the next step. Think firstly if the value that the user puts there is not paciente.nombre but is something else. **Don´t I need to test the binding** firstly?And anyway the error that outputs shouldnt be there, cause paciente.nombre is not undefined

Comment: How could it be something else ? Your binding is on `paciente.nombre`, and it's hard coded. If you want to test that the values entered are correct, you will do end-to-end tests, not unit tests. Here, you only have to test if your application behvaes as you expect, not if the user is entering the good format. Because if you do so, you will duplicate your tests (unit + e2e).

Comment: You mean that field validation is not part of unit testing? If I wanna test if teh user has entered numbers or text or somthing else, can I do this on unit testing

Comment: No, I mean testing if the framework works isn't part of unit testing. You can test if the user has entered correct values (number in number, string in string) during form validation, when you submit it. And you test if the user has entered valid values (number > 0 for instance) in e2e testing. In your case, you test if the binding works. Let Angualr manage that, that's not your job.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much. If possible can you provide me with some links or doc about unit testing the form validation. I usually find for model driven forms, but not for template driven forms of angular which I am using. testing id th user entered numbers or text f.e.

Comment: Angular doc too doesn´t talk about this part.

Comment: I'll make an answer to explain it, it's faster and more concise, wait a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comments, here is how to test if a form is submitted correctly.

Let's say you have an interface `Patient` :

```
export interface Patient {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

In your component, you have a form, and you submit it through `submit()` :

```
submit() {
  this.patientService.savePatient(this.patient).subscribe(result => {
    console.log('Patient created');
  });
}
```

Now your service make the HTTP call and checks if the fields are okay :

```
savePatient(patient: Patient): Observable<any> {
  if (typeof patient.id !== number) { return Observable.throw('ID is not a number'); }
  if (typeof patient.name !== string) { return Observable.throw('Name is not a string'); }

  return this.http.post<any>(this.url, patient);
}
```

Then your tests should look like this. First, the component :

```
it('Should call the service to save the patient in DB', () => {
  // Spy on service call
  // Expect spy to have been called
});

it('Should log a message on success', () => {
  // Spy on console log
  // Expect console log to have been called with a string
});
```

You can also test if the error is treated correctly, if you have error codes, etc.

Now in the service :

```
it('Should throw an error if the ID is not a number', () => {
  // Mock a patient with a string ID
  // Expect an error to be thrown
});

// Same thing for the name, you get the idea

it('Should make an HTTP call with a valid patient', () => {
  // Spy on the HttpTestingController
  // Expect the correct endpoint to have been called, with the patient as the payload
});
```

The general idea of those tests is **to cover any case that could happen**. This will allow you to prevent *side effects* : for instance, if one day you decide to pass your ID to string, the unit test will fail and tell you

> You expect me to send a string but I pass only with a number

This is the purpose of a unit test.

Comment: Well thanks a lot. But I needed to concretize my question a bit more, so everybody can have things clear on how to test form submitting on anular.

Comment: You should make a new question, this is getting too blurry, people won't understand a thing.

Comment: Can you please concreatize just the test of validation if the ID is not a number?? Or have a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524398/unit-testing-an-input-in-angular