# Adding validators in angular forms

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am testing this html form:

```html
 <input #nhcInput type="text" class="form-control" name="nhc" id="field_nhc"
                 [(ngModel)]="paciente.nhc" maxlength="38" pattern="[0-9]+"/>
             <div [hidden]="!(editForm.controls.nhc?.dirty && editForm.controls.nhc?.invalid)">
                 <small class="form-text text-danger"
                    [hidden]="!editForm.controls.nhc?.errors?.maxlength" jhiTranslate="entity.validation.maxlength" translateValues="{ max: 38 }">
                    This field cannot be longer than 38 characters.
                 </small>
```

```html
TEH RESULT {{nhcInput.className}} //This line prints ng-valid/ dirty, touched correctly
```

I have this in my component:

```html
    paciente: Paciente = {nhc: '23423' } as Paciente;
```

```html
  it ('NHC cannot have more than 38 characters', async(() => {
               
                      comp.paciente.nhc = 'rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr' ;             
                      console.log(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[name="nhc"]').className);
                      fixture.detectChanges();              
                     expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[name="nhc"]').className.includes('ng-invalid')).toEqual(true);
                      }));
```

Now I want to test the validity by checking the vaidator.
The console.log prints out only form-control without the type of validator, since it is not finding it.

I put a validator for this fild like this in my component:

```html
@ViewChild('editForm') editForm: any;
 editform.controls["nhc"].setValidators([ Validators.maxLength(38)]);
```

But this doesnt work. Am I doing soemthing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that you don't do things in order and don't rely on the framework to make your tests.

[I made a sandbox](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-fghqld?file=app/hello.component.ts) with a working test, feel free to look at it. Now for the explanation :

Let's start with the component :

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `
  <form #myForm="ngForm">
    <input type="text" maxlength="20" name="patient" id="patient" [(ngModel)]="patient">
  </form>
  `,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent  {
  @ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;
  patient: string;
}
```

A very simple component with a template driven form and a basic validation and binding.

If you do this

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log(this.myForm.controls);
  setTimeout(() => console.log(this.myForm.controls));
}
```

You will see both `undefined` and `{ patient: FormControl }`. This happens because you don't wait for the view to be initialized before doing your tests. This means that the test can't find the form control, and hence can't pass.

Now for the test itself :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

describe('HelloComponent', () => {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HelloComponent>;
  let component: HelloComponent;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [FormsModule],
      declarations: [HelloComponent]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HelloComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should be invalid with more than 20 chars', async(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      component.myForm.controls['patient'].setValue('ddddddddddddddddddddd'); // 21
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(component.myForm.control.invalid).toEqual(true);
    });
  }));
});
```

the start is very basic, test bed is configured and changes are detected.

Now comes the part where you test : you first must wait for the component to load with a timeout, then, you need to set the value on the form by using the framework :

```
component.myForm.controls['patient'].setValue('ddddddddddddddddddddd'); // 21
```

This inputs 21 `d` into the input, which is making it invalid. After that, you need to trigger the changes detection, and now you can make your expectation with

```
expect(component.myForm.control.invalid).toEqual(true);
```

This will take the form as a control, meaning it has all the properties and functions a FormControl has. Among these, you can find the `invalid` property, which states if your control is in an invalid state.

Again, I have to state that this kind of test is useless, because you basically try to see if the Framework is working properly. That's not your job, that's Angular team's job. If you want to test something, you should test that the form can't be submitted when it has an invalid state, which is a business rule (I guess) and prevents side effects (unlike this test).

Comment: But for the purpose of the test, I ma testing if it outputs the errors in the case of something invalid. And since teh submitt button is disabled on invalid datas this means it cannot sumbit invalid values

Comment: And cant I use validators to output the className of the element?

Comment: Again, this kind of test is useless, Angular will display the error message and hide the buttons given your conditions. You don't need to test if Angular works, only if your business logic is coping with your expectations. And instead of testing the className, you should directly test if the element is display through a `ViewChild` reference.

Comment: component.myForm.controls['paciente.nhc'].setValue it says cannot take setValue of undefined. Inside controls can I put teh reference of teh viewChld of teh nhc? And what type should it be ElementRef?

Comment: Why did we move from this  expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('input[name="apellidos"]').className.includes('ng-invalid')).toEqual(true); to this new type of test. I like more teh one with class Name cause you can test pristine and dirty too

Comment: Either way the test is useless, but I moved to this syntax because it's more reliable (to me) than testing for classes. and every form control has `dirty`, `pristine`, `valid`, `invalid`, `touched`. The classes are just mirroring those states. Go ahead, see for yourself, the autocompletion will offer your all the states.

Comment: Ok but why teh setValuesays that myForm.controls is undefined. I have this in my component  paciente: Paciente = {nhc: '23423' } as Paciente;

Comment: ... You really need to start focusing when you read answers. `This happens because you don't wait for the view to be initialized before doing your tests. This means that the test can't find the form control, and hence can't pass`

Comment: By I should wait for the component to load with a timeout you mean to insert this code: ngOnInit() { console.log(this.myForm.controls); setTimeout(() => console.log(this.myForm.controls)); }

Comment: And on your sandbox thetest fails. Shoudnt it pass. In my test it passes othrwisewith 21 or 19 charcts. Is thre something I a missing?

Comment: No, I mean you should wait for your component to load the view. How you do it is up to you., but I would rely on lifecycle hooks. And the test passes in my sandbox, I don't know what you're talking about.

Comment: Ok, now I see!! So your test works perfectly! I am having problems with my app only. I put the same code inside my app, but I do not see the dddddddd in my input when I run my app, like in your sandbox. I dont know why this happens but this is the reason why my test doesnt work.

Comment: And there were no need for validators or smth else. The other test with class Nme works perfectly again in the sandbox. It is the probem in my app, eventhough I dont get what is it

Comment: What may it be?? I got the exact code just like in the sandbox, inside my app and I dont see anythink in my input when running the app

Comment: Is it something to worry about when it comes to testing? That even though the test works perfectly in my app too, I dont see the input to be filled with things I write in my test?