# hasAttribute in DOM not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, testing, protractor

I have this form in an tect.html file and I want to test if the button is disabled or not:

```html
<button id="ref_button"....[disabled]="editForm.form.invalid || isSaving" class="btn btn-primary">
```

I am using protractor, cucumber, and chai dom to test if this button is disabled when the form data are invalid, so I check its attribute disabled like this:

```html
  JSDOM.fromFile("file.html").then(dom => {
   dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").has.attr('disabled').should.be.true;
     
    });
  });
```

Now the test fails because it always finds the attribute disabled, when the button is disabled or not, when the datas are valid or not.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the attribute `[disabled]` does NOT exist on button element( that's why it's always true). It's the attribute `disabled` which you have to look for( without `[` and `]` markup. It's binding syntax.

So when thinking about it,  this should work: (did not test...)

```
dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").should.not.have.attr("disabled");
```

But probably this will always output `false` since a button does have that attribute. To make this consistently work you should take the value of the `disabled` attribute and check wheter it's true.

```
dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").getAttribute("disabled").toBeTruethy().
```

I actually don't know if `toBeTruethy()` does exist in chai but my point here is, that you should check the value of an attribute and not just if an attribute exists in general.

One other thing to mention is this:

```
element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']")).click();
element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']")).sendKeys('').then(callback);
```

I guess `click()` is also an asynchronous function and in above example keys are sent before `click()` has finished it's execution. This would be correct I think:

```
element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']")).click().then(function() {
  element(by.css("*[id='field_nombre']")).sendKeys('').then(callback);
});
```

Comment: Yell, yess to respond to your doubt, it never finds 'disabled', but only ['disabled'] in both cases when data is valid and invalid

Comment: How about `element(by.css('ref_button').isEnabled().then(function(isEnabled) { /* verify it should be true or false here... */ });` ?
I forgot about that function but it should exactly check what you want to check.

Comment: As per your doubt if the func are asynchronous, I see the steps executed and sending the right data in my browser during tests, perfectly. As per the suggestion dom.window.document.getElementById("ref_button").hasAttribute('disabled').should.be.true; gives always false.

Comment: I modified my question

Answer (score 0):

For angularJs, you should use directive `ng-disabled` in your html

from official [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled):

> A special directive is necessary because we cannot use interpolation
>   inside the disabled attribute. See the interpolation guide for more
>   info.